# Is there any way to return my json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, instagram

I am recently writing a Javascript Web Application in which the users can go through public Instagram profiles and download the images.

Therefore I am using JSON objects which store all information from a user's profile.

My function looks like this:

```
receiveProfile(username) {
    var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1";

    var resultObject;

    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {

        resultObject = new UserProfile(
            data.graphql.user.full_name,
            data.graphql.user.biography,
            data.graphql.user.profile_pic_url,
            data.graphql.user.external_url,
            data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges,
            data.graphql.user.edge_followed_by,
            data.graphql.user.edge_follow
        );

        return resultObject;
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("Booo");
    });

    return resultObject;
}
```

I have an Instance of an object called "JsonService" which gets the return-value of this method, in other words the UserProfile of a certain user. The UserProfile will then be stored as field of my JsonService. But when I set my field 
`this.userProfile = receiveProfile(username);` and try to console.log it, it always shows "undefined" in my browser.

How can I correctly pass the object to the field of my JsonService.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your function returns before the `fetch` completes, so it will always return undefined

Comment: One possible solution for this situation is to use called `Promise`, read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank you for your answer norbitrial. I read the documentation and understood the pros of using a promise, but now I do still have some questions for my implementation of this method. Should I  now put my fetch-structure inside of a Promise?

Comment: Oh now I got it.  Simply added a "return" in front of the fetch so the whole fetch gets returned and it instantiated a new Promise which includes my UserProfile object. Thanks for all of your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
>   method returns a
>   [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
>   that resolves to the
>   [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)
>   to that request, whether it is successful or not.

`receiveProfile` function returns `resultObject` (which is undefined initially) before `fetch()` block finishes. It should wait for the promise to resolve.

You have 2 options:

### 1. With async/await

```
async receiveProfile(username) {
    const url = `https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`;

    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return new UserProfile(
        data.graphql.user.full_name,
        data.graphql.user.biography,
        data.graphql.user.profile_pic_url,
        data.graphql.user.external_url,
        data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges,
        data.graphql.user.edge_followed_by,
        data.graphql.user.edge_follow
    );
}
```

Demo:

```js
// Dummy class
class UserProfile {
    constructor(full_name, biography, profile_pic_url, external_url, edges, edge_followed_by, edge_follow) {
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.biography = biography;
        this.profile_pic_url = profile_pic_url;
        this.external_url = external_url;
        this.edges = edges;
        this.edge_followed_by = edge_followed_by;
        this.edge_follow = edge_follow;
    }
}

async function receiveProfile(username) {
    const url = `https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`;

    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return new UserProfile(
        data.graphql.user.full_name,
        data.graphql.user.biography,
        data.graphql.user.profile_pic_url,
        data.graphql.user.external_url,
        data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges,
        data.graphql.user.edge_followed_by,
        data.graphql.user.edge_follow
    );
}

receiveProfile('instagram').then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

### 2. Without async/await

```
receiveProfile(username) {
    const url = `https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`;

    return fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        return new UserProfile(
            data.graphql.user.full_name,
            data.graphql.user.biography,
            data.graphql.user.profile_pic_url,
            data.graphql.user.external_url,
            data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges,
            data.graphql.user.edge_followed_by,
            data.graphql.user.edge_follow
        );
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
// Dummy class
class UserProfile {
    constructor(full_name, biography, profile_pic_url, external_url, edges, edge_followed_by, edge_follow) {
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.biography = biography;
        this.profile_pic_url = profile_pic_url;
        this.external_url = external_url;
        this.edges = edges;
        this.edge_followed_by = edge_followed_by;
        this.edge_follow = edge_follow;
    }
}

function receiveProfile(username) {
    const url = `https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`;

    return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        return new UserProfile(
            data.graphql.user.full_name,
            data.graphql.user.biography,
            data.graphql.user.profile_pic_url,
            data.graphql.user.external_url,
            data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges,
            data.graphql.user.edge_followed_by,
            data.graphql.user.edge_follow
        );
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
    });
}

receiveProfile('instagram').then(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer. The only missing part is: How do I store the output from this in a variable?

Comment: You can do it in `then()` callback since `fetch()` returns a Promise. `let userProfile; receiveProfile('instagram').then(function (user) { userProfile = user; });`